# Compare numpy arrays of different sizes

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have two arrays of points with xy coordinates:

```
basic_pts = np.array([[0, 0], [1, 0], [2, 0], [0, 1], [1, 1], [0, 2]])
new_pts = np.array([[2, 2], [2, 1], [0.5, 0.5], [1.5, 0.5]])
```

As result I want from the array `new_pts`only those points, that fulfil the condition that there is no point in `basic_pts`with a bigger x AND y value. So a result would be

```
res_pts = np.array([[2, 2], [2, 1], [1.5, 0.5]])
```

I have a solution which works but because of working with list comprehension it is not suitable for a bigger amount of data.

```
x_cond = ([basic_pts[:, 0] > x for x in new_pts[:, 1]])
y_cond = ([basic_pts[:, 1] > y for y in new_pts[:, 1]])
xy_cond_ = np.logical_and(x_cond, y_cond)
xy_cond = np.swapaxes(xy_cond_, 0, 1)
mask = np.invert(np.logical_or.reduce(xy_cond))
res_pts = new_pts[mask]
```

Is there a better way to solve this only with numpy and without list comprehension?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use [`NumPy broadcasting`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.1/user/basics.broadcasting.html) -

```
# Get xy_cond equivalent after extending dimensions of basic_pts to a 2D array
# version by "pushing" separately col-0 and col-1 to axis=0 and creating a 
# singleton dimension at axis=1. 
# Compare these two extended versions with col-1 of new_pts. 
xyc = (basic_pts[:,0,None] > new_pts[:,1]) & (basic_pts[:,1,None] > new_pts[:,1])

# Create mask equivalent and index into new_pts to get selective rows from it
mask = ~(xyc).any(0)
res_pts_out = new_pts[mask]
```

Comment: This was my thought as well; note however that it ends up creating an intermediate `(len(basic_pts), len(new_pts))` intermediate array, which can be pretty memory intensive (OP mentioned 'big amounts of data')

Comment: @val Yeah that could be an issue with really huge datasizes. Thanks for pointing that out!

Answer (score 0):

As val points out, a solution that creates an intermediate `len(basic_pts)` × `len(new_pts)` array can be too memory intensive. On the other hand, a solution that tests each point in `new_pts` in a loop can be too time-consuming. We can bridge the gap by picking a batch size *k* and testing `new_pts` in batches of size *k* using Divakar's solution:

```
basic_pts = np.array([[0, 0], [1, 0], [2, 0], [0, 1], [1, 1], [0, 2]])
new_pts = np.array([[2, 2], [2, 1], [0.5, 0.5], [1.5, 0.5]])
k = 2
subresults = []
for i in range(0, len(new_pts), k):
    j = min(i + k, len(new_pts))
    # Process new_pts[i:j] using Divakar's solution
    xyc = np.logical_and(
        basic_pts[:, np.newaxis, 0] > new_pts[np.newaxis, i:j, 0],
        basic_pts[:, np.newaxis, 1] > new_pts[np.newaxis, i:j, 1])
    mask = ~(xyc).any(axis=0)
    # mask indicates which points among new_pts[i:j] to use
    subresults.append(new_pts[i:j][mask])
# Concatenate subresult lists
res = np.concatenate(subresults)
print(res)
# Prints:
array([[ 2. ,  2. ],
       [ 2. ,  1. ],
       [ 1.5,  0.5]])
```